# Arithmetic sequence in a list of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence

For a given set of numbers

```
3 5 3 6 3 4 10 4 5 2
```

I wish to find all the `**triplets**` which form a arithmetic progression.

```
like (3,3,3) (3,4,5) (6,4,2) (3,4,5)
```

I have a trivial O(n^3)  solution. I was wondering if it can be done it time O(n^2) or less.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I just removed the C++ tag.

Answer (score 5):

`O(n^2 * logn)` can be achieved by:

1. Sort the array - O(nlogn)
2. iterate all pairs (O(n^2) of those) - and for each pair (x,y) do a binary search to see if you have: `max{x,y} + abs(x-y)` or `min{x,y} - abs(x-y)` as an element.

   Special care should be taken for pairs where `x==y` - but it can be easily solved within the same time complexity.

Note that this solution will give you 1 occurance of each triplet (no duplicates).

(**EDIT:** by using a hash table ([histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) if you care for the number of triplets ) and look in it instead of sorting the array and using binary search - you can reduce the time to `O(n^2)` on average, with the cost of `O(n)` additional space).

---

Without the 1 occurance drawback - it cannot be done better then `O(n^3)`, because there could be `O(n^3)` such triplets, for example in the array `[1,1,1,...,1]` - you have `chose(3,n)` such triplets.

Comment: You're wrong with the second part - you can use two binary searches to find the lower and upper bound of the number you're looking for and count how many of it there are.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev: You can *count* how many there are - but not to output them - which seems to be what the OP is asking.

Comment: you can reduce this to O( n^2 ) by adding a hash table for the lookup of third member

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You are correct, I added indication for it. thanks.

Comment: Why do we need to do the binary search? As far as I see it, we are done after the first sort. Just print all possible tripplet-combinations. Every combination x,y,z can be print xyz and zyx. They always follow the given requirements, because of the previous sort.

Answer (score 1):

One can use hashing to solve it in `O(n^2)` by choosing a middle element and then choosing first and last element in `O(n)`.

This is simple question of finding two numbers in a array whose sum is fixed. Here, `a+c` should be `2b`.

Therefore, all I look for `a` & `c` such that `a+c=2i`.